# Mat-table displaying new Array

Tags: angular

I am downloading from the backend object category containing categories, name and category type. I want to display several mat-tables, each for different types. When I display all categories, I do not have any problem with it, but I want to create new mat-table objects to display the tables separately. The console shows that the objects have been correctly created but do not display in HTML - the place is empty

```
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'watki', 'id'];
  categories: Category[]  = [];
  programmingCategories: Category[] = [];

  constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService,
              private _router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCategories();
  }

  private getCategories() {
    this.categoryService.getAllCategories().subscribe((categories: any) => {
      this.categories = categories._embedded.categories;

      for(let i of this.categories)

       if(i.categoryType ==='Programowanie') {
        this.programmingCategories[i.id-1] = i;
        }
      }

    });
  }
```

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="programmingCategories" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Programowanie </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let category">
      <mat-icon mat-list-icon>assignment</mat-icon>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Kategoria</th>
      <td class="link" mat-cell *matCellDef="let category" (click)="getTopics(category)">
        {{category.title}}
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="watki">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Liczba wątków</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let category"> 
        {{category.size}}
      </td>

    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Ostatni post</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let category">
        <table><tr><td height="20" class="link">{{newestPost[category.id]?.topic?.title}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td height="20">Przez {{newestPost[category.id]?.postAuthor?.username}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td height="20" style="font-size:10px">  {{newestPost[category.id]?.createdDate | date: 'medium'}}</td></tr>
        </table>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

  </table>
```

Comment: you want to display several tables or several columns ?

Comment: if you wish to display several tables, your gonna need to do ngFor on the mat-table.
else how would you think it will make few tables?

Comment: in next step i will make something like in html code that i posted but with different dataSource, i have ,,categories" from backend and i want to make other array objects by it and use them to create few mat-tables

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but in case anyone needs a way to do this. I'm not using the example above, so you can copy/paste this into a fresh angular project.

What I'm doing is using a method as the datasource in our table, and that method is filtering our full dataset in the component based on a passed in parameter from the table.

The table gets this parameter to pass in by doing an ngFor on the value in the "positions" array, which would be the data we want to use to split our tables. This can be hard-coded (yuch!) like in this example, or you can make this a dynamically populated array (yay!).

In your module, for this example, import MatTableModule from @angular/material.

In our app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent { 
    outputData = [{ name: 'Alpha', position: 'front' }, 
                  { name: 'Beta', position: 'back' },
                  { name: 'Gamma', position: 'front' }, 
                  { name: 'Delta', position: 'back' }];
    positions = ['front', 'back'];

    sourceData(position: string) {
        return this.outputData.filter(data => data.position === position);
    }
}
```

and in app.component.html

```
<table mat-table *ngFor="let position of positions" [dataSource]="sourceData(position)">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let output"> {{ output.name }} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Position </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let output"> {{ output.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['position', 'name']"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['position', 'name'];"></tr>
<table>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjyasx
[image: Output]